# Matrix Multiplication in R without using %*% or crossprod

Tags: r, matrix, matrix-multiplication, cross-product

I am trying to multiply two matrix in R without using %*% or crossprod. 
what i have tried so far

```
x <- matrix(1:4, ncol = 2)
y <- matrix(5:8, ncol = 2)
MatMul <- function(X,Y)
{

  t(apply(x,1,crossprod,y))

}

MatMul(x,y)
```

I want to multiply without using crossprod or %*%

I' m totally stuck on this problem since quite some time... Hence any help is extremely welcome.

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: x <- matrix(1:4, ncol = 2)
y <- matrix(5:8, ncol = 2)
 This are two matrices for ex.

MatMul <- function(X,Y)
{
    t(apply(x,1,crossprod,y))
}


MatMul(x,y)

I want to multiply without using %*% or crossprod as illustrated above

Comment: Yes. I am doing a research work. so as instructed , i dont have to use it.

Comment: your code above use crossprod, but you wrote that you are not allowed to use it.

Comment: @edouard Yes.. i have done it using crossprod. But i am not allowed to use it. that is why i am searching for an alternative

Comment: @1089  It is okay.  I just notified because you commented before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I could think of solving it, is using embedded `for` loops (my first ever since 2013...)

The function

```
MatMult <- function(x, y){
  res <- matrix(NA, dim(x)[1], dim(y)[2])
    for(i in seq_along(y[1, ])){
     for(j in seq_along(x[, 1])){
      res[j, i] <- sum(x[j, ] * y[, i])
     }
    }
  res
 }
```

Your matrices

```
x <- matrix(1:4, ncol = 2)
y <- matrix(5:8, ncol = 2)
```

Testing

```
MatMult(x, y)
##      [,1] [,2]
## [1,]   23   31
## [2,]   34   46

x%*%y
##      [,1] [,2]
## [1,]   23   31
## [2,]   34   46
```

Comment: Seems there are some bugs in the program. You haven't defined x dimensions. probably it will return NA's while multiplying x = matrix(1:8, ncol = 4) ,y = matrix(1:20, ncol = 5). I suggest you a edit in the code and define x while defining demo matrix.

Comment: well instead of hiding your error by complete.cases, why not use res <- matrix(NA, dim(x)[1], dim(y)[2]). It will solve all the problem.

Comment: Just wanted to share. I also used firstly complete.cases, later found out.

Comment: Ok, modified it per your suggestion. I didn't have enough time to think of it right now as I'm at work right now

Answer (score 1):

You may also try: (if the dimensions are the same)

```
indx <- rep(seq(dim(x)[1]), each=dim(x)[1])
res <- apply(x,1, `*`,y) ##assuming that this is okay
res1 <- do.call(`cbind`,by(res, indx, FUN=colSums))
dimnames(res1) <- NULL
res1
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]   23   31
#[2,]   34   46
```

Or

```
t(colSums(array(apply(x,1, `*`, y), c(dim(x),dim(x)[1]))))
#    [,1] [,2]
#[1,]   23   31
#[2,]   34   46
```

#### Update

```
 x <- matrix(seq_len(9), 3,3) 
 y <- matrix(seq_len(12), 3,4)

 dim1 <- do.call(`pmax`, list(dim(x), dim(y)))
  t(colSums(array(apply(x,1, `*`, y), c(dim1,dim(y)[1]))))
 #    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 #[1,]   30   66  102  138
 #[2,]   36   81  126  171
 #[3,]   42   96  150  204
```

Comment: You can't use `x` as the dims of your result. It won't work in case `y` is larger. Check your code for `x <- matrix(seq_len(9), 3,3) ; y <- matrix(seq_len(12), 3,4)`

Comment: @1089 I updated the code.  I haven't checked it extensively.  There could be bugs. David Arenburg; I updated with your example

Comment: @akrun thanks.. i think it works(so far i have checked)